# Format Cell Based on List from Another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

We have a list that is generated based on a form: employees fill out the form when completing a training course. All responses are in the 'Form Responses 1' sheet. On another sheet, we have a summary table, that is currently updated by hand.

What we would like to do is have the summary update when a respondent submits the form.

Here is an example sheet: [Training Verification Log](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jkG515zyl4UxRHxhtFTjgWsjG0aBE4vsOxbpvqgjogU/edit?usp=sharing)

So when Bob submits the form for training course SP128, the summary sheet will change the value from blank to Yes. On the summary, SP134X and SP135X must be manually entered as the value they submit is not what is displayed and can be left out.

What kind of formula would I need to check the name on the summary with the response list, and the course number submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A3 can be:

```
={"Employee"; "Name"; INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE({REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 1'!B2:B, "\d+")*1, 
 TRIM('Form Responses 1'!B2:B)})),,2)}
```

and F5 can be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A5:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A5:A, 
 QUERY({TRIM('Form Responses 1'!B2:G)}, "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col6"), MATCH(F2:P2, 
 QUERY(QUERY({TRIM('Form Responses 1'!B2:G)}, "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col6"), "limit 0", 1), 0), 0))&"", "\d+", "yes")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @player0 ! Could you please provide a descriptive answer along with your solution so that other users with similar doubts can understand it ? If you also include links to the appropiate documentation it would also be great. Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jkG515zyl4UxRHxhtFTjgWsjG0aBE4vsOxbpvqgjogU/edit#gid=536376041 form data are pivoted via QUERY and then simple VLOOKUP is used to output MATCHing columns in 3rd VLOOKUP argument. query counts are then converted via REGEXREPLACE to "yes". done.

Comment: @player0 Just out of curiosity, could "yes" be replaced with the date from one of the columns?

Comment: @JohnSpartan sure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIM8w.png

Comment: Rock on, That's what I figured, apparently I had it wrong - thanks for the example!